# When I must stop my actors?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, akka, playframework-2.1

I start my actor in controller in Play 2. I read somewhere that I must stop my actors. When I stop it as in example below I got the problem that file do not upload at all. When I comment it starts uploading it.

```
    //Akka 
    ActorSystem system = Akka.system();
    ActorRef uploader = system.actorOf(new Props(UploaderActor.class), "uploader");
    uploader.tell(new Uploader(post.id, "/public/images/post/",post, request()), uploader);
    //system.stop(uploader);
```

Please help.

**My question is: When I must stop my Actors?**

One additional question:

*How can I access this actor in another controller(get this reference) ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to create a long-lived uploader that you send the upload-messages to, and it can internally create new actors to handle the actual uploads and shut them down if need be. This frees the client, you, from managing the life-cycle.

Answer (score 2):

If this actor is meant to be short lived and only process a single request, then you can have the actor stop itself in the `receive` method after it's done like this:

```
getContext().stop(getSelf());
```

That way you can be sure the actor is done before being stopped.  For your second question, if you want to look up this actor instance from somewhere else, all you need is a reference to the actor system that it is running in.  If you have that then it's just:

```
ActorRef ref = system.actorFor("/user/uploader")
```

If you are going to be spawning multiple uploaders at a time then be sure to name them uniquely.  The name you give it when starting it is the name you can use to look it up from some other piece of code.

Comment: I must find method to identify is the actor finish it's work. But I can't find it

Comment: No. An actor processes its mailbox asynchronously. When u send a message to it control immediately returns to the caller more than likely before the actor has had a chance to process the message. By making the actor stop itself from inside you can ensure its done before stopping it.

Comment: You could also consider `ask` instead of `tell`. That way you get a future back that you can block on until the message is done being handled by the actor. Just make sure you respond back to the sender inside of the actor when done.

Comment: I do this . Thank you. I don't understand that I can do inside :)